# Why is xspeed != 0?

Tags: rotation, geometry, angle, trigonometry

I'm making a game in which the player should move in its facing direction.
So I've come up with this.

```
int speed = 50;
float rotation = 90;

int speedx = speed * cos(rotation);
int speedy = speed * sin(rotation);
player->move(speedx, speedy);
```

But the problem is this:`cos(90)` returns `-0.448074` and `sin(90)` returns `0.893997`. They should return `0` and `1`.

Does any one of you have an idea why?

Comment: What language are you writing in? Please add it as a tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your `cos` and `sin` functions are expecting angles in radians, not degrees.

[Cosine of 90 radians is -0.448074 as you've found.](https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=cos%2090%20rad)